# Как выстроить класс взаимодействия с методами API на Android?

Tags: java, android, api, request, okhttp

Новичок в Android, хочу сделать чтобы у меня был отдельный класс с реализацией запросов к API, к примеру.
У меня есть какое-то Activity и я хочу получить данные о пользователе, не выполняя громоздкий запрос, а получить примерно так:

```
User owner = Api.getUserById(userId);
```

или через callback:

```
Api.getUserById(userId, new Callback(){...})
```

Сейчас я сделал следующее:

[image: Метод получения информации профиля]

[image: Отправка асинхронного запроса]

getProfileInfo(String, Callback); я хочу вызывать внутри Activity, и чтобы в callback возвращался уже мой объект User либо Ошибка, а не Response.

Помогите довести такую архитектуру до ума или подскажите как лучше.

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Здесь все зависит от ваших знаний принципов, умений, привычек и тд. Организовать такую работу можно разными способами я бы посоветовал использовать Retrofit + GsonConverter, посмотрите в эту сторону

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На середину 2018 года рекомендуемым подходом от Google будет:

- использование репозитория, который получает данные
  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#fetching_data
- он может хранить их в кэше или брать из сети
  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#caching_data
- Данные уже приезжают через LiveData в том виде в котором вам надо ViewModel
  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#connecting_viewmodel_and_the_repository
- Также вы можете делать обертку для отражения сетевого статуса 
  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum